# spray.io upgrade causes missing mock library in specs2

Tags: scala, spray, specs2, spray-test

I use specs2 in my spray.io project.  It all works fine and when I use the following versions.

```
val akkaV = "2.3.6"
val sprayV = "1.3.2"
val specs2V = "2.3.11"
```

However, recently I tried to upgrade the akka and spray version to the following.

```
val akkaV = "2.3.9"
val sprayV = "1.3.3"
```

When I run my tests now, I get the following error.

> object mock is not a member of package org.specs2

I'm not sure how the spray or akka versions affect specs2, but I somehow find this behaviour very odd.  I tried different versions of specs2, even the latest one, but the error persists.

Comment: Can you post the actual specs2 modules you use? There's specs2 and specs2-core, and using the wrong one may lead to the error. Also, you may want to use the sbt-dependency-graph sbt plugin which could show which modules your project uses exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to add `specs2-mock` to your build.

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.specs2/specs2-mock
libraryDependencies += "org.specs2" %% "specs2-mock" % "4.3.5" % Test
```

Comment: That worked, just strange that I didn't need this package for a different version of akka and spray.  Can you give some more details as to why this occurs?

Comment: Maybe they were pulling in this dependency for you and they stopped doing it?